# If flesh & blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God how did the Lord Jesus show His "hands and feet" after the resurrection?

Tags: gospel-of-luke, textual-discrepancies, 1-corinthians, resurrection-of-jesus, resurrection-body

As blood and flesh can't inherit the Kingdom of God, how could the Lord Jesus be resurrected with same blood and flesh? I mean He showed his hands and feet to the disciples in Luke 24:39. Or is that meaning He was in flesh and blood only 40 days earthly living after his resurrection?

> Look at my hands and my feet. It is I myself! Touch me and see; a ghost does not have flesh and bones, as you see I have.” ([Luke 24:39](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+24%3A39&version=NIV), NIV)
>
> I declare to you, brothers and sisters, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable. ([1 Corinthians 15:50](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+15%3A50&version=NIV), NIV)

What is the meaning of "the perishable inherit the imperishable"? Or will we be resurrected with the same body and flesh?

Comment: If you're of a mind to be charitable to Paul you can assume he simply meant that the flesh and blood must be improved via the resurrection first.

Comment: I think you need to start by asking "What does it mean that blood and flesh cannot inherit the Kingdom of God".

Comment: @steve Neither human mind nor earthly knowledge can understand the will of Father and things in heaven; this is why Lord said to Peter like that, kindly note:

Comment: @Loay Jesus was referring to the specific knowledge uttered in response by Peter, not all knowledge.

Comment: `flesh and bones` vs `flesh and blood` ...different wording

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/30551/23657. Related

Answer (score 3):

Man  in  his  present  state  is  mortal,  and  corruptable and  cannot  enter  the  kingdom  of  God.

1 Corinthians 15;53
For   this  corruptable  must  put  on  incorruption,  and  this  mortal  must  put  on  immortality.

Philippians 3;21
Who  shall  change  our  vile  body,  that  it  may  be  fashioned  like  unto  his  glorious  body,  according  to  the  working  whereby  he  is  able  to  subdue  all  things  unto  himself.

Answer (score 3):

V.Rollins is right.  Read the verse in it's entirety it is talking about corruption vs. incorruption:

" 50 Now this I say, brethren, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God; neither doth corruption inherit incorruption."

Symbolism changes throughout the bible from one verse to another.  In one instance "blood" is referring to mortality, which can die and wither (ie - corrupt).  In another it may refer to life, as in the case of of Christ's blood, which He gave for us.  You must read the scriptures in context of what it is speaking about.  In 1 Corinthians the topic is mostly about spiritual vs. things of the world.  Remember these are letters from Paul addressing specific needs of people in different areas.  The Christians in Corinth needed to be made wary of worldliness and that it has no place in the kingdom of God.

Answer (score 1):

I shall tackle this question with a systematic approach. All verses used are in KJV.

Before that, though, let’s talk about Luke 24:39,

> Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have.

In this verse, Jesus is resurrected in flesh and blood like an actual human being. He is telling His disciples that He is neither a ghost nor some demon spirit conjured by Satan to fool them, but He is Himself, literally, in the flesh. Flesh and blood in this scenario does not refer to sins of the flesh or worldly desires, it must be taken in the literal context.

Below will be the systematic approach on understanding who are those “flesh and blood” that cannot enter the kingdom of heaven. Firstly, we ask ourselves,

## Who can inherit the kingdom of heaven?

Definitely not Jesus! He is the King of kings and the Lord of lords, how can a king inherit something that is of his possession? Much less the Lord Himself? Jesus did not come to earth as the Son of God to inherit the kingdom of heaven as the Son of man, He came down to proclaim the Word of God so that we, may.

Matthew 4: 17

> From that time **Jesus began to preach**, and to say, Repent: for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.

Mark 1: 14-15

> 14 Now after that John was put in prison, Jesus came into Galilee, **preaching the gospel of the kingdom of God**,
>
> 15 And saying, The time is fulfilled, and the kingdom of God is at hand: repent ye, and believe the gospel.

## What does the Bible say about those who can enter the kingdom of heaven?

Anyone who receives Christ can enter the kingdom of heaven.

1 John 5:11-12

> 11 And this is the record, that God hath given to us eternal life, and this life is in his Son.
>
> 12 **He that hath the Son hath life**; and he that hath not the Son of God hath not life.

John 3: 16

> For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, **that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life**.

## Okay, that sounds easy enough. So, what is the Bible’s definition of belief/faith?

An action faith manifested through good works!

James 2:14-26

> 18 Yea, a man may say, Thou hast faith, and I have works: shew me thy faith without thy works, and I will shew thee my faith **by** my works.
> 19 Thou believest that there is one God; thou doest well: **the devils also believe, and tremble.**
> 20 But wilt thou know, O vain man, that **faith without works is dead**?
> 21 Was not **Abraham our father justified by works**, when he had offered Isaac his son upon the altar?
> 22 Seest thou how faith wrought with his works, and **by works was faith made perfect**?
> 23 And the scripture was fulfilled which saith, Abraham believed God, and it was imputed unto him for righteousness: and he was called the Friend of God.

Believe, in the biblical context, is not just the mental capacity of admitting the existence of someone or events, it is your actions that defend (justify) your faith. For if one believes in Christ, one would follow Him and His righteous way. Just like in school, if you believe the mathematical formula is the right one, you would use it and not use another! How can you say you believe it is the right one yet refuse to use it? It would **show** that you didn't believe in the first place or didn't believe enough.

## A Summary

Accept Jesus Christ as Son of God and Saviour, repent of your sins and be righteous in all your ways and works. Through you shall God's glory be revealed to those who have not yet receive Christ because people can see your works and may make the decision to come to Christ! The second commandment is to love your neighbours as yourself. If you love your neighbours, you would want them to be saved through Jesus Christ as well.

When a christian is righteous, they will also keep God’s commandments.

## Since the righteous can enter the kingdom of heaven, it means the unrighteous can’t. What does the Bible say about unrighteous people?

1 Corinthians 6:9-11

> 9 Know ye not that **the unrighteous shall not inherit the kingdom of God?** Be not deceived: **neither fornicators, nor idolaters, nor adulterers, nor effeminate, nor abusers of themselves with mankind,**
> 10 **Nor thieves, nor covetous, nor drunkards, nor revilers, nor extortioners, shall inherit the kingdom of God.**
> 11 And such were some of you: but ye are washed, but ye are **sanctified**, but ye are **justified in the name of the Lord Jesus, and by the Spirit of our God**.

Revelation 21:8

> 8 **But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars, shall have their part in the lake which burneth with fire and brimstone**: which is the second death.

Basically, all the bad people who refuse to repent of their sins and continue sinning, cannot enter the kingdom of heaven.

## How do you connect the unrighteous people to the "flesh and blood" that cannot enter the kingdom of heaven?

Here is where we come to the phrase "sins of the flesh" and "worldly desires". Evident in various verses!

1 John 2:15-17

> 15 Love not the world, neither the things that are in the world. **If any man love the world, the love of the Father is not in him.**
> 16 For all that is in the world, **the lust of the flesh**, and the lust of the eyes, and the pride of life, is not of the Father, but is of the world.
> 17 And the world passeth away, and the lust thereof: but he that doeth the will of God abideth for ever.

Love of the world = Worldly desires = Anything that is not the Will of God for the believer.

Lust of the flesh =  Sexual immorality = sin, sin, sin!

Galatians 5:19-21

> 19 Now the **works of the flesh** are manifest, which are these; Adultery, fornication, uncleanness, lasciviousness,
> 20 Idolatry, witchcraft, hatred, variance, emulations, wrath, strife, seditions, heresies,
> 21 Envyings, murders, drunkenness, revellings, and such like: of the which I tell you before, as I have also told you in time past, that **they which do such things shall not inherit the kingdom of God.**

## HOLD UP. Does this not sound just like the sins of the unrighteous people from other verses?

Yes! The flesh manifests many sins! Lust, envy, pride, wealth, the list goes on! Hence, the flesh and blood that cannot enter the kingdom of heaven does not actually mean that as long as we are in our flesh, we cannot enter even though we've accepted Christ. **Flesh and blood that cannot enter the kingdom of heaven is the sins of the flesh and the worldly desires that is not of the Will of God.** So, don't worry! Just 'cause we are human, we can still inherit the kingdom of God!

## Besides, have you heard of the phrase, the Spirit wars against the flesh?

It is derived from Galatians 5:17

> For the flesh lusteth against the Spirit, and the Spirit against the flesh: and these are contrary the one to the other: so that **ye cannot do the things that ye would**.

What are the things that you would do? But cannot because the Holy Spirit is strong in you? For example, before you were christian, maybe you would throw a profanity here and there when you were extremely angry. However, after you became a christian and began to **follow Christ**, you toned down or completely did away with the swearing. This is part of the **good works** - when people see the change in you, they see the **glory of God in you** because you can now **glorify His Name** by saying, "I believe in God and Jesus, the Lord has changed me and I am starting to **control** myself now." This is known also as the **works of faith** and called the **testimony of the Word of God**. Are these words familiar to you? They should!

How can one say he believes in Jesus yet swears up and down whenever he wants? This is because the **flesh is strong**! When the flesh is strong, **it manifest many nasty things**. Swearing is one of them, or someone who is quick to anger, or rapist, adultery, many many **sins**, I dare say **ALL SINS**, come **from the flesh**. And these fleshly sins will **deny** the "believer" the kingdom of heaven.

I end this long wall of text with relevant verses from Proverbs 15, **anything in brackets are my own interpretation.**

> 1 A soft answer turneth away wrath: but **grievous words** stir up anger.
>
> 3 **The eyes of the Lord are in every place, beholding the evil and the good.**
>
> 8 **The sacrifice of the wicked (even when he accepts Christ) is an abomination to the Lord**: but the prayer of the upright is his delight.
>
> 9 The way of the wicked is an abomination unto the Lord: **but he (The Lord) loveth him that followeth after righteousness (The Way).**
>
> 10 Correction is grievous unto him that forsaketh the way: and **he that hateth reproof shall die.** (Hate God's discipline or commandments)
>
> 16 **Better is little with the fear of the Lord than great treasure (wealth, desires) and trouble therewith.**
>
> 17 **Better is a dinner of herbs (simple needs) where love is, than a stalled ox (feasting) and hatred therewith.**
>
> 18 A wrathful man stirreth up strife: **but he that is slow to anger appeaseth strife.**
>
> 19 **The way of the slothful man is as an hedge of thorns: but the way of the righteous is made plain.** (in the sight of the Lord, God recognises good works done in faith)
>
> 20 **A wise son maketh a glad father: but a foolish man despiseth his mother.**
>
> 21 Folly is joy to him that is destitute of wisdom: but **a man of understanding walketh uprightly.** (If you really believe, you would follow God's ways)
>
> 24 The way of life is above to the wise, that he may **depart from hell (don't sin)** beneath.
>
> 25 **The Lord will destroy the house of the proud (no kingdom of heaven for pride, one of the seven deadly sins!)**: but he will establish the border of the widow.
>
> 26 **The thoughts of the wicked are an abomination to the Lord**: but the words of the pure are pleasant words.
>
> 29 **The Lord is far from the wicked (no kingdom of heaven for them either)**: but he heareth the prayer of the righteous.
>
> 33 **The fear of the Lord is the instruction of wisdom; and before honour is humility. (humble yourselves and repent)**

Comment: I like this answer because it is what the early church taught.  So you believe man will be ressurected in this same flesh and bones  right?

Answer (score 1):

**What is the truth the perishable inherit the imperishable? Or will we be resurrected with the same body and flesh?**

I think the key to this is found in the idea that the exact physical bodies we have now will die. The resurrection bodies we get will still be physical but different. With Jesus as an example of this type of body.

> 1 John 3:2  Beloved, now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet
>   appear what we shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we
>   shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is.

Jesus was able to interact with the disciples physically.

> Luke 24:39  Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle
>   me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have.
>
> John 21:13  Jesus then cometh, and taketh bread, and giveth them, and
>   fish likewise.
>
> Luke 24:32  And they said one to another, Did not our heart burn
>   within us, while he talked with us by the way, and while he opened to
>   us the scriptures?

However the resurrection body Jesus has could appear and disappear.

> Luke 24:31  And their eyes were opened, and they knew him; and he
>   vanished out of their sight.
>
> Luke 24:36  And as they thus spake, Jesus himself stood in the midst
>   of them, and saith unto them, Peace be unto you.

The resurrection body of Jesus could also ascend.

> Acts 1:9  And when he had spoken these things, while they beheld, he
>   was taken up; and a cloud received him out of their sight.

The assertion that flesh and blood cannot enter the kingdom of heaven is probably better phrased, flesh and blood as it is and by themselves cannot enter the kingdom of heaven. The key to entrance into the kingdom is the new life to be found by faith in Jesus. It is this new life that allows for the transformation of our physical bodies to a new type of body of which Jesus was an example.

> 1 Corinthians 15:52  In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the
>   last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised
>   incorruptible, and we shall be changed.

While the record of Jesus after his resurrection is brief and we do not have a specific description of his eating and drinking, we do know that when the kingdom is finally come, he will be drinking and so shall we.

> Matthew 26:29  But I say unto you, I will not drink henceforth of this
>   fruit of the vine, until that day when I drink it new with you in my
>   Father's kingdom.

Our resurrection bodies will be quite similar to our present bodies but have additional properties of which we only have hints at present.

Answer (score 0):

The  saints  will  resurrect  with  a  body  like  unto  his  glorious  body.

Philippians 3;20-21  For  our  conservation   is  in  heaven;  from  whence  also  we  look  for  the  Saviour,  the  LORD  Jesus  Christ:  Who  shall  change  our  vile   body,  that  it  may  be  fashioned  like  unto  his  glorious  body,  according  to  the  working  whereby  he  is  able  even  to  subdue  all  things  unto  hemself.

Answer (score -1):

Blood is the key, flesh with blood will not enter the Kingdom of God, wherein flesh and bones will enter the Kingdom of God.

> 1 Corinthians 1:50 flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God
>
> Luke 24:39 Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have.

Old Testament Commands regarding blood:

> Genesis 9:4 But flesh with the life thereof, which is the blood thereof, shall ye not eat.
>
> Leviticus 17:11-14 For the life of the flesh is in the blood: and I have given it to you upon the altar to make an atonement for your souls: for it is the blood that maketh an atonement for the soul. Therefore I said unto the children of Israel, No soul of you shall eat blood, neither shall any stranger that sojourneth among you eat blood. And whatsoever man there be of the children of Israel, or of the strangers that sojourn among you, which hunteth and catcheth any beast or fowl that may be eaten; he shall even pour out the blood thereof, and cover it with dust. For it is the life of all flesh; the blood of it is for the life thereof: therefore I said unto the children of Israel, Ye shall eat the blood of no manner of flesh: for the life of all flesh is the blood thereof: whosoever eateth it shall be cut off.

So the life of the believer is in the blood of Christ not in our mortal blood.

Comment: Sorry, but your argument is weak.

Comment: @Steve, My point is that the combination of flesh and (mortal) blood will not enter the Kingdom of God, but that does not hold that flesh and bone will not enter the Kingdom of God.

Comment: But you may be right, perhaps it is weak!

Answer (score -1):

Jesus was resurrected as a human to prove that he was resurrected.

When he said "see my hands and feet" he was still in his human body 
that was nailed to the torture stake, but was now brought back to life.

He didn't ascend to heaven (Gods Kingdom) until later,
when he returned to his spirit form.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you're a new visitor, I'd like to recommend the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)