# Is it possible for a spirit to eat fish?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-luke, resurrection-of-jesus, resurrection-body

Is it possible for a spirit to eat fish? Then how did Jesus eat fish after his resurrection (Luke 24:43).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Jesus specifically said after his resurrection that he was *not* a spirit: "See my hands and my feet, that it is I myself. Touch me, and see. For a spirit does not have flesh and bones as you see that I have" (Luke 24:39).

Comment: I don't believe the answers to this question are only opinion-based. The question demonstrates a flawed premise, which is easily dispelled.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'd be inclined to agree except that there are some who have associated with Christianity who *do* think post-resurrection Jesus was only a spirit.  If the OP was specifically asking about Nicene Christianity, for example, then I'd agree with you, but he could also be asking about the beliefs of Jehovah's Witnesses, in which case the existing answer is out of place.

Answer (score 14):

Most branches of Christianity believe that Jesus rose from the dead ***bodily*** (*ie* he wasn't merely a spirit at that point). The very context of the verse you are referring to, is that he was eating the fish to show he was ***not*** a ghost to his disciples:

> **Jesus Appears to the Disciples**
>
> <sup>36</sup> While they were still talking about this, Jesus himself stood among them and said to them, “Peace be with you.”
>
> <sup>37</sup> They were startled and frightened, **thinking they saw a ghost**. <sup>38</sup> He said to them, “Why are you troubled, and why do doubts rise in your minds? <sup>39</sup> Look at my hands and my feet. It is I myself! Touch me and see; **a ghost does not have flesh and bones, as you see I have.**”
>
> <sup>40</sup> When he had said this, he showed them his hands and feet. <sup>41</sup> And while they still did not believe it because of joy and amazement, he asked them, “Do you have anything here to eat?” <sup>42</sup> They gave him a piece of broiled fish, <sup>43</sup> and he took it and ate it in their presence. - [Luke 24:37-43 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2024%3A37-43&version=NIV), *emphasis added*

A related question along these lines is found here: [How similar was the resurrected body of Jesus to his physical human body?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30551/how-similar-was-the-resurrected-body-of-jesus-to-his-physical-human-body/30553#30553)